# Find URLs in text and wrap in anchor tag

Tags: ruby

I'm basically writing my own Markdown parser. I want to detect a URL in a string and wrap it with an anchor tag if it's a valid URL. For example:

```
string = 'here is a link: http://google.com'
# if string matches regex (which it does)
# should return:
'here is a link: <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>'

# but this would remain unchanged:
string 'here is a link: google.com'
```

How can I achieve this?

Bonus points if you can point me to the code in an existing Ruby markdown parser that I can use as an example.

Comment: What protocols do you want to allow? `http://`? `https://`? `ftp://`? `irc://`? `telnet://`?

Comment: Here's how they do it in Kramdown: <https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown/autolink.rb>

Comment: Note: you have to remove the final bracket in the link above to make it work.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek thanks for the link, however, I'm having trouble getting it to work: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/c4e0b

Answer (score 11):

In general: use a regular expression to find URLs and wrap them in your HTML:

```
urls = %r{(?:https?|ftp|mailto)://\S+}i
html = str.gsub urls, '<a href="\0">\0</a>'
```

Note that this particular solution will turn this text:

```
See more at http://www.google.com.
```

…into…

```
See more at <a href="http://www.google.com.">http://www.google.com.</a>
```

So you may want to play with the regex a bit to figure out where the URL should really end.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this jquery plugin 
http://www.jquery.gr/linker/